# Is it possible to assign the CategoryID value to CategoryInfo object?

Tags: c#, kentico

I've been trying to add a new category by using the following block of code:

```
CategoryInfo category = new CategoryInfo()
{
    CategoryID = 999, // manually set
    CategoryName = "TestCategory",
    CategoryDisplayName = "Test Category",
    CategoryEnabled = true,
    CategorySiteID = 1
};

CategoryInfoProvider.SetCategoryInfo(category);
```

This doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't add the new category to         `CMS_Category` table.

However, if I removed this line: `CategoryID = 999,`, the category gets saved into the system and the CategoryID is automatically assigned.

I would like to set this field manually. Any help is appreciated.
(I am trying to avoid creating additional fields to handle this)

Answer (score 3):

Kentico decides whether to save or update an object based on whether its primary key is set. So if `CategoryID` is set the system actually calls `UPDATE CMS_Category SET ... WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID` instead of `INSERT INTO ...`

If you need to store the original reference (I'm guessing that you are trying to store an external identifier for integration purposes) I'd suggest storing it in a separate field. And to prevent modifying system fields, I'd utilize the code name field - `CategoryName`.

Though what @martin suggests seems like a good idea, I'm pretty sure it won't work as Kentico would lose the reference to the object that's currently being updated. If you have a valid source code license, look at the `CategoryInfoProvider.SetCategoryInfoInternal()` to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, it was only guess. I have already tried it and it does not work (because of mentioned reasons).

Comment: Thank you @rocky, Yes, I am trying to store an external ID. I am going to give it a try by using the categoryName field to store this identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I haven`t tried it but you can try to change ID of category after create, something like:

```
[CustomCategoryID] 
public partial class CMSModuleLoader 
{ 
private class CustomCategoryID : CMSLoaderAttribute 
{ 
    public override void Init() 
    { 
        CategoryInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.After += Insert_After; 
    } 

    void Insert_After(object sender, CMS.DataEngine.ObjectEventArgs e) 
    { 
        var category = e.Object as CategoryInfo; 
        if (category != null) 
        { 
            category.CategoryID = 999, // manually set
            category.Update(); 
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

- Are you sure the system does not store your new category but with different ID (that you provide)?
- Could you please tell me why do you want to customize object ID behavior? Thanks

Comment: Hi @martin, I have some records I need to save to the database, where  categoryID and CategoryParentID are predefined. I need to set the CategoryID as I have to set dependencies over the ParentCategoryID. I am trying to avoid extra lines of code to create a new mapping for setting up categories and subcategories.